# Given an XElement, how do I retrieve a reference to another relative XElement/Xattribute given an XPath?

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, xelement

Given the following XML:

```
<SomeXML>
    <Element1>
        <Element2 Attribute3="Value4" />
    </Element1
</SomeXML>
```

... and an XElement reference to 'SomeElement' and an XPath 'Element1/Element2/@Attribute3'

**How do I retrieve a reference to Attribute3 so that I may alter it's value (using the Xpath)?**

The XPath is to be a retrieved setting and thus is my only way of locating the node in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `using System.Xml.XPath` to the code file where you need to do this.

Then you can use code like this:-

```
 var attrib3 = someElement.XPathEvaluate("Element1/Element2/@Attribute3") as XAttribute;
 if (attrib3 != null)
     attrib3.Value = "new value";
```

Comment: Today you are my personal hero :D Excellent stuff

Answer (score 4):

using `System.Xml.XPath`

and the extension method [XPathSelectElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on your XElement

Comment: Also a great answer. It's just a shame I can't actively split the points.